# how can i extract my query to find average

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table like this

```
  name  M1    m2   Tot
  a      20   30    50
  b      10   20    30    
  a      20   10    30
  a      30   15    45
```

By Using query

```
SELECT name,
    ISNULL([1],0) AS tot1,
    ISNULL([2],0) AS tot2,
    ISNULL([3],0) AS tot3
 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) RN,
              name, Total
       FROM  T
      ) S
 PIVOT (MAX(Total) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
```

I got out put like

```
name   Tot1  Tot2  Tot3
 a      50     30    45
 b      30     0      0
```

now i need to add one more column to find Average. So I need output like

```
name   Tot1  Tot2  Tot3  **Avg**
 a      50     30    45    **42**
 b      30     0      0    **10**
```

how can i extract my query..

Comment: Check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968596/how-to-pivot-and-calculating-column-average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT name,
    ISNULL([1],0) AS tot1,
    ISNULL([2],0) AS tot2,
    ISNULL([3],0) AS tot3,
    (ISNULL([1],0) + ISNULL([2],0) + ISNULL([3],0) )/3 AS [AVG]
 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) RN,
              name, tot
       FROM  Example
      ) S
 PIVOT (MAX(tot) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select q.*, (tot1 + tot2 + tot3) / 3
from q;
```